# ¿Por que aparece error "Constant expression contains invalid operations" en clase conexion usando PDO en PHP?

Tags: php, pdo

Poseo la siguiente clase conexión orientada a objetos con PDO:

**Conexion.php:**

```
<?php namespace Models;

$archivo = 'config.ini.php';
$configurar = parse_ini_file($archivo, true);

$host= $configurar['basedatos']['host'];
$user = $configurar['basedatos']['user'];
$pass = $configurar['basedatos']['pass'];
$db = $configurar['basedatos']['dbname'];
$charset = $configurar['basedatos']['charset'];

    class Conexion extends PDO
    {
        private $_datos = array(
            "host" => $host,
            "user" => $user,
            "pass" => $pass,
            "dbname" => $db,
            "charset" => $charset
            );

        protected static $_conexion; /* private $_conexion */

        private function __construct() {
            try 
            {
                self::$_conexion = new PDO("mysql:
                    host=$this->_datos['host'];
                    dbname=$this->_datos['dbname'];
                    charset=$this->_datos['charset']", 
                    $this->_datos['user'], 
                    $this->_datos['pass']);

                self::$_conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                    echo "Conexion Exitosa"; 
            }

            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                echo "Conexion Fallida: " . $e->getMessage();
            }
        }

        public function consultaSimple($sql) {
            $this->_conexion->query($sql);
        }

        public function consultaRetorno($sql) {
            $datos= $this->_conexion;
            return $datos;
        }
    }
```

**Config.ini.php:**

```
<?php return; ?> ; 
[basedatos]
driver="mysql"
host="localhost"
port="3306"
user="root"
pass="" 
db="escuelaCRUD"
charset="utf8"
```

El error mostrado es:

> Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations in
>   Conexion.php on line 14

Comment: Se parece a la forma en que uso la conexión en mi Clase de Github, pero tienes varios errores en ella. Por ejemplo usas variables que no son conocidas cuando se invoca el constructor de la clase ... entre otras cosas. Si usas el código como está en la clase te funcionará a la perfección. https://github.com/padrecedano/PHP-PDO

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias de nuevo por la libreria, habia perdido el link, esta la estaba haciendo por mi cuenta basandome en unos tutoriales y una de github, te la pasare cuando pueda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Modifique la posicion del codigo para parsear el archivo INI
- Agregue algunos atributos
- Agregue el use PDO, para evitar el error de clase global, evite usar \ en cada PDO

  ```
  use PDO;
  class Conexion 
  {
      private $_host;
      private $_user;
      private $_pass;
      private $_dbname;
      private $_charset;
      private $_conexion; /* private $_conexion */

      public function __construct() {
          $archivo = 'config.ini.php';
          $configurar = parse_ini_file($archivo, true);

          $this->_host = $configurar['basedatos']['host'];
          $this->_user = $configurar['basedatos']['user'];
          $this->_pass = $configurar['basedatos']['pass'];
          $this->_dbname = $configurar['basedatos']['dbname'];
          $this->_charset = $configurar['basedatos']['charset'];
          try 
          {

          $this->_conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->_host;
                  dbname=$this->_dbname;
                  charset=$this->_charset", 
                  $this->_user, 
                  $this->_pass);
           $this->_conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                  echo "Conexion Exitosa"; 
          }

          catch(PDOException $e)
          {
              echo "Conexion Fallida: " . $e->getMessage();
          }
      }

      public function consultaSimple($sql) {
          $this->_conexion->query($sql);
      }

      public function consultaRetorno($sql) {
          $datos= $this->_conexion;
          return $datos;
      }
  }

  $conexion = new conexion();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Dentro del objeto PDO, al momento de realizar la conexion no puedes usar $this->Xvariable, te lo digo por experiencia, me ha pasado, debes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
    private function __construct() {
        try 
        {
            self::$_conexion = new PDO("mysql:
                host=$host;
                dbname=$dbname;
                charset=$charset", 
                $this->_datos['user'], 
                $this->_datos['pass']);

            self::$_conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                echo "Conexion Exitosa"; 
        }
```